# Displaying multiple products with foreach loop with different rows in db

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, foreach

I have an application with Orders. So in the db there is a record with TableID
Date, Time, ProductID and how many times that product is ordered. When a product is ordered but its on the same table and date and time it should be on the same receipt. but it displays different(See photos). I already order them by date and time. but when i group it by TableNr it doesnt display multiple items from the same tableNr (see 2nd photo)

Photo 1:
[image]

Photo 2:
[image]

[image: db]

```
<?php

  $checkbestelling = "SELECT *, gerecht.Prijs*bestelling.Aantal AS Totaalprijs FROM  bestelling 
    LEFT JOIN menuitem ON bestelling.MenuItemID = menuitem.MenuItemID
    LEFT JOIN gerecht ON gerecht.GerechtID = menuitem.GerechtID ORDER BY Datum, Tijd ASC";
    foreach ($db->query($checkbestelling) as $bestellingen){ 
    ?>

 <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Tafel <?php echo $bestellingen["Tafel"];?></h5>
            <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period">Datum: <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($bestellingen["Datum"]));?></span></h6>
            <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period">Tijd: <?php echo $bestellingen["Tijd"];?></span></h6>
            <hr>
           <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
            <li class="list-group-item nb">Product: <?php echo $bestellingen["Gerecht"];?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item nb">Aantal: <?php echo $bestellingen["Aantal"];?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item nb">Prijs: €<?php echo $bestellingen["Totaalprijs"];?></li>         
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary bgcb" onclick="printDiv('printable')">Print bon</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary bgcr">Verwijder</button>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: And you say you only change the " order by"?

Comment: @Amarnasan When I add Table to the order by nothing happens. and when i add group by Table it results in image nr2

Comment: Ok, so you left the important stuff out: You add a "group by" and didn't expect the results to change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is on your Query, you are Ordering them by Date, but you should be grouping them by date ("GROUP BY") too, so it groups all the rows from the same date.

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(foo), DATE(mydate) FROM a_table GROUP BY DATE(a_table.mydate);
```

Comment: But when I group them by table time and date it doesnt show multiple products that are on that same date. it loops through the products and then shows only 1 product instead of 2 or 3 that needs to be on the receipt

Comment: In that case you should Group By date and then by "Tafel"  which would be the table attended at that time, right?.